# Differentiate between font typeface in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, typeface

I am having trouble figuring out how to differentiate between a fonts typeface that I am using for a web page I am building for a college class. I am using the **EXO** font courtesy of Natanael Gama from over at fontsquirrel.

With this font he includes 18 typefaces. I am interested in using the 'Exo-Thin' typeface for my webpage instead of the parent 'Exo' typeface coded in the @font-face. (I think 'Exo' defaults to the 'Exo-Regular' typeface but I am not sure.) How do I format my css to read this properly?

**-- Here is my @font-face code --**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Exo;
    src: url("/Macintosh\ HD\ 1/Library/Font/CustomFonts_Webfonts/Exo.ttf")
          format("truetype"),
          url("/Macintosh\ HD\ 1/Library/Fonts/ConvertedFonts_Webfonts/Exo.woff") format("woff");
}
```

From here, how would I represent the typeface value within the font-family property throughout the rest of the sheet? I'm new to this kind of work and it's been bugging me that I can't find anything on the internet that would describe what needs to be done.

If you can post any advice or point me in the direction of any previous posts regarding/any websites covering this coding I'll be thankful.

If any admins have to delete and redirect me, I'm cool with that.

Thanks for any help, overflow peoples. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I just had to add the typeface like this --->

**-- @font-face code --**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Exo;
    src: url("/Macintosh\ HD\ 1/Library/Font/CustomFonts_Webfonts/Exo-Thin.ttf")
          format("truetype"),
          url("/Macintosh\ HD\ 1/Library/Fonts/ConvertedFonts_Webfonts/Exo-Thin.woff") format("woff");
}
```

I just added in the typeface into the url path.